# Как запоминать выделенную запись в DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Работаю с *WPF* и *MVVM*. Как мне после обновления коллекции выделять запись, которая была выделена в `DataGrid` (то есть `SelectedIndex`)?

Comment: Давно работал на C#, если не ошибаюсь, то работать надо с SelectedIndex. А в переменную сохранить никак?) Или что у вас там за проблема?

Comment: @Пандакун: А как у вас происходит обновление коллекции? Если вы просто добавляете элемент в `ObservableCollection`, по идее выделенный элемент должен сохраниться.

Comment: @VladD по Command привязаной к кнопке, которая отсылается на метод:

public void RefreshCollection()
{ 
   PaketCollecion = DataBase.GetPakets()
   //возвращается ObservableCollection<part>
}

Comment: @Пандакун: О! Вы ж уничтожаете старую коллекцию, и полностью заменяете на новую. Неудивительно, что фокус не сохраняется. Вам придётся запоминать фокус. Проще всего сделать свойство `IsFocused` (или `IsSelected`) в VM и привязать его к View.

Comment: @VladD Привязал свойство SelectedIndex к полю в ViewModel. Всё запоминает но после обновления коллекции ничего не выбирается почему-то.

Comment: @Пандакун: Хм. Покажите код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы ж уничтожаете старую коллекцию и полностью заменяете на новую. Неудивительно, что фокус не сохраняется. Вам придётся запоминать фокус. Проще всего сделать свойство `IsFocused` (или `IsSelected`) в VM и привязать его к View.

---

Когда вы добавляете новую запись, вам нужно [установить selected row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15826902/276994) и возможно [отскроллировать к нему](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd324321%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).